# exists and no exists mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-select-db

i have data dummy like this

```
CREATE TABLE A  ( users_id INT);
INSERT INTO A  VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
CREATE TABLE B (users_id INT);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2), (3), (4), (5);
CREATE TABLE C (users_id INT);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (3), (4), (5), (6);
CREATE TABLE D (users_id INT);
INSERT INTO D VALUES (4), (5), (6), (7);
```

i want to selected users_id where exists on table D and B but NOT EXISTS on table A

i tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT b1.users_Id FROM b b1
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT d1.users_Id FROM D d1
                WHERE b1.users_id = d1.users_id)
       AND NO EXISTS (SELECT a1.users_id from A a1
                      WHERE a1.users_id = d1.users_id
                      and a1.users_id = b1.users_id
                      and b1.users_id = d1.users_id);
```

but the mysql said

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT a1.users_id from A a1 WHERE a1.users_id = d' at line 4
```

here's the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bff8e/10

Comment: Sql speaks properly, so "NOT" instead of "NO" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate form of same query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.users_Id
FROM b
JOIN d
  ON b.users_id = d.users_id
LEFT JOIN a
  ON b.users_id = a.users_id
WHERE a.users_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thankyou very much sir, this is exactly what i need, have a good day.